# Python2.7 searches the unwanted directory when importing modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonpath, python-2.4, python-import

I tried to use Python 2.7 to import `numpy`.

Configuration that may cause the problem

- Two Python interpreter installed on my computer, Python `2.4` and `2.7`
- **two** copies of `numpy` installed, one in my home directory, which is the desired one, the other one in the Python 2.4 place, `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/`, which is undesired.

Also, I set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to contain the necessary path to import the desired `numpy` copy.

But Python 2.7 searches where Python 2.4's default module installation path is, in my case,the `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages`.

How can this happen?

Comment: What does `import sys; print sys.path` give you?

Comment: It prints out the path `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages`! Thanks for this good tip. I think I have more clues now.

Comment: in python 2.7? What does `sys.executable` print?

Comment: It prints out the path of Python interpreter I use `/software/python.2.7.3/bin/python`

Comment: Good, then you didn't accidentally mix up your python installations and your sys.path does have a problem, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks! I think I know where to get started now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find where the inclusion comes from you can put the following at the top of your program before other imports:

```
import sys
sys.path.remove('/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages')
```